# android studio - too many apks after using build apk or release feature

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, apk

I am trying to **build an apk from build apk feature** in the android studio. But I found something like **the attached image**. I never found this kind of apks ever, and I don't know how come this occurs. Can anybody explain what are those apks and why it's happening?

[image: These are the apks that I have got.]

My build.gradle file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 30
    buildToolsVersion "30.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.sakhawat.youtubedownloader"
        minSdkVersion 23
        targetSdkVersion 30
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}

compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}

splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
        universalApk true
    }
}

}

dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'
// circle image view
implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.1.0'

//lottie animation loader
implementation 'com.airbnb.android:lottie:2.5.0-rc1'

//youtube play library
implementation 'com.github.yausername.youtubedl-android:library:0.12.+'
implementation "com.devbrackets.android:exomedia:4.3.0"

//rx android
implementation "io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.0"

//google admob
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.3.0'
```

}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your **build.gradle** file contains a splits block.

Please read [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/configure-apk-splits#configure-split) for more information.

**[EDIT]**

As i 've told you above your build.gradle file seems to contains a splits block.
So here it is

```
splits {
    abi {
        enable true
        reset()
        include 'x86', 'x86_64', 'armeabi-v7a', 'arm64-v8a'
        universalApk true
    }
}
```

Please comment out this block, then try to build an apk again and let us know for the generated APKs.

Comment: I also thought that my build.gradle would be the reason but I didn't find any issue. I can share with you the Gradle, it would be amazing if you can have a loot at it.I am updating my question with gradle image too.